# Is SIP protocol routeable

Tags: networking, routing, sip

I have a sip-able PBX. My Sipdroid phone works on local network. From outside I route the traffic thru a firewall. Even all rules are ok I cannot connect to the PBX with sip when traffic is routed.

Is there anything else to have in count when using SIP in routed networks ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIP is IP, so yes it's routable. That said, it is tricky to get it to play well with NAT. Verify that your firewall rules are ok, both for signaling (5060) and RTP (most cases 10000-20000).